# setwise convergence of signed measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ be a standard Borel space. Consider a non-negative function $\mu(t,B)$, where $t \in [0, \infty[$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(X),$ such that:

(i) for each $B$ the function $\mu(t, B)$ is absolutely continuous in $t$;

(ii) for each $t$ the function $\mu(t, \cdot)$ is a measure on  $(X, \mathcal{B}(X));$

(iii) $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mu(t,\cdot)$ is a signed measure on $ (X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ whenever the derivative exists.

Then, for some bounded measurable function $g(y), y \in X$, does the following the following inequality hold for almost every $t$?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_B g(y) \mu(t, dy) \ge \int_B q(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mu(t, dy).$

Comment: Do you mean $g$ instead of $q$ in the RHS of the last inequality?